# Entity typed primary key IDs with Entity Framework - expression tree insanity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to find a way to get strongly-typed primary keys in EF Code First. My goal is to make it impossible to accidentally assign one type of ID to another. Here's an example of what an entity with such a beast applied to it might look like:

```
public partial class AccessMethod : BaseEntity
{
    internal virtual Guid ID_
    {
        get { return ID.Value; }
        set { ID = new ID<AccessMethod>(value); }
    }
    public ID<AccessMethod> ID { get; set; }

    internal virtual Guid LocationID_
    {
        get { return LocationID.Value; }
        set { LocationID = new ID<Location>(value); }
    }
    public ID<Location> LocationID { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    #region Navigation properties

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Here's the code for `ID<>`:

```
public class StrongID<T, TEntity> : IEquatable<StrongID<T, TEntity>>
{
    readonly T _value;

    public StrongID()
    {
        _value = default(T);
    }
    public StrongID(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get { return _value; } }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is StrongID<T, TEntity>)
        {
            return Equals(obj as StrongID<T, TEntity>);
        }

        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode() ^ (_value == null ? 0 : _value.GetHashCode());
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ID<" + typeof(T).Name + ">(" + _value + ")";
    }

    public bool Equals(StrongID<T, TEntity> other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;

        var thisIsNull = this._value == null;
        var otherIsNull = other._value == null;
        if (thisIsNull || otherIsNull) return thisIsNull == otherIsNull;

        return this._value.Equals(other._value);
    }

    //commented for now
    //public static implicit operator T(StrongID<T, TEntity> id)
    //{
    //  return id.Value;
    //}
}

public class ID<TEntity> : StrongID<Guid, TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public ID() { }
    public ID(Guid id) : base(id) { }
}
```

The idea is that EF is made aware of `ID_`, but this property is hidden from the rest of the project and is exposed through `ID`, which as you can see includes the type of the entity.

Since I'm using explicit mappings for my entities, I was able to write a base class which uses reflection to automatically ignore `StrongID<>` properties and map properties with the same name plus an underscore to a column with the underscore removed.

I know that EF doesn't support custom types at all for primary keys, only .NET's built-in scalar types. So I'm going the insane route of modifying the expression tree of all queries, changing all accesses to `ID` to point to `ID_` instead (and do the same for other `ID<>` properties like `LocationID`).

I have an `IQueryProvider` wrapper that invokes an `ExpressionVisitor` in its `CreateQuery()` methods. This seems to work fine. I was going to try hooking into the `Execute()` methods instead, but `ToList()` uses `GetEnumerator()`, which never calls `Execute()`, so that wasn't going to work. This way will probably work better in the end anyway.

Unfortunately, this is where my plan starts to fall apart. Expression trees are ridiculously complicated to work with and have many nuances about them, and it's impossible to know where you'll have access to what without running real code and examining things.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class ConvertStrongIDExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression is ParameterExpression)
        {
            if (IsTypeStrongID(node.Type))
            {
                var ntex = node.Expression as ParameterExpression;
                if (typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(ntex.Type))
                {
                    //ntex.Type is an entity type, node refers to a strongid member on that type
                    var property = ntex.Type.GetProperty(node.Member.Name + "_", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(node.Expression, property);
                }
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        if (IsTypeStrongID(node.Type))
        {
            var value = node.Type.GetProperty("Value").GetMethod.Invoke(node.Value, null);
            return Expression.Constant(value);
        }

        return base.VisitConstant(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        return base.VisitLambda<T>(node);
    }


    bool IsTypeStrongID(Type t)
    {
        var strongIDType = typeof(StrongID<,>);

        while (t != null)
        {
            if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == strongIDType) return true;
            t = t.BaseType;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what other methods I will need to override, and I have no idea if I'm using `ExpressionVisitor` correctly to begin with. `VisitMember()` and `VisitConstant()` both seem to work okay. Currently, I get this exception (it happens to be generated while in `VisitLambda()`):

```
Reference equality is not defined for the types 'System.Guid' and 'Core.ID`1[Core.Domain.Location]'.
```

The expression that it's barfing on is this:

```
o => o.LocationID == new ID<Location>(locationID)
```

I thought that the expression `new ID<Location>(locationID)` was being turned into a constant? It seems to not be? This is why I'm unsure of my usage of ExpressionVisitor. It seems like expressions don't get visited in any particular order. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

UGH, I just realized that this won't work with anonymous types at all, because they won't have the mirror properties. I'd have to dynamically create a new type, swap it into the expression tree, and fix up everywhere that any of the original type's properties is referenced. Doable, but that sounds like a NIGHTMARE.

And then there's the currently-unknown performance implications of all of the above...

So I guess I'm wondering things like, does anyone have any ideas as to how I can make this concept work well? Has anyone tried anything like this before, either with EF or another ORM? Should I submit a feature request to the EF folks and start a discussion there?

Your thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: This is a really interesting conundrum you're dealing with, but it would be a better fit for this site if you ended with a focused, answerable question we could tackle. Please do! We could get some good thoughts on this. :)

Comment: Well okay, I didn't really make my question more specific, but I am still curious as to how to resolve the exception I'm getting. I can't continue my efforts until that's taken care of. Maybe I should post some example code somewhere...